# how to create theme based widget that can be drop in sider bar or footer

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I am developing a installable theme in wordpress I have created a contact form and called that form in footer but I want to create a widget that should be theme based mean i dont want any plugin.I can create a widget but for this i need to put the file in plugin folder that I don't want that should be completely theme based .

I want this because if I want to change the position of contact form like from footer to sidebar so for this I need to make this contact form widget that can be drag and drop in footer and sidebar.

I have searched this also on Internet but all are based on plugin directory so that Its not my requirement because it will activate whenever plugin will be activate  but I need widget should activate whenever theme will be activate

Please provide me help or your suggestion
I shall be very thankful to you 
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why it have -ve vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A contact form is pure plugin stuff. It has to survive a theme switch. Put it into a plugin and prepare your stylesheet for the common possible positions.

Comment: I don't want this through plugin I have already mention in my question then why you are giving me the plugin suggestion.And its not long form it have only three field.I just want to do this functionality through function.php hope now the question is clear

Comment: @admin Answers on this site should help anybody with the same problem or question. And my advise is not to put a contact form into a theme. I’ve done that and regretted it.

Comment: @admin I completely agree with what @tocho is saying here. I too have added things like contact forms to themes in the past and it is a really bad idea. All it amounts to is more work that needs to be done during theme switch. The best thing that you can do is to register the widget in a plugin.

Comment: @mfields @toscho I dont understand why you guys not concentrate on my question doesn't matter to implement a contact form in theme is good or bad but its requirement and to change requirement is not in my hand and I can't give you so much explanation further more at the end conclusion is its a requirement and I cant change.

Comment: @mfields @toscho And you can understand requirement is not in our hand it based on client.Right row contact form is in footer I want to create a widget for this contact form with the help of this widget we can drag and drop contact form in sidrbar or footer(Where I need)

Comment: You *can* put any plugin code into your theme too, and it will work.

Comment: @toscho thanks alot Can you provide me any link just for help.

Comment: @admin If you have a working plugin, put the file(s) into your theme directory and `require` the main file in the `functions.php`. That’s all.

Comment: @toscho Thanks alot its working And i apologies for some my rude word which i used  for you.Actually you can understand we cant change requirement