# What page should I use for a contact form?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I want to make a theme with an about page and a contact form,

Should I make a custom page meant specifically for it? (the blog is ment for mobile and I'm not looking for most flexibility, the page can be all hard coded but the text)
And how would such page be created from the WP-Admin?

Comment: A theme should [never contain a contact form](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18002/73). That’s plugin territory.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true.  I have a contact form that users can enable with theme options which allows them to input the destination e-mail.

Comment: @siouxfan45 Technically possible `!==` makes sense. Users should have a choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building a custom theme, I'd recommend creating [custom page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Examples_of_Pages_and_Templates) - one each for an About and a Contact page.

This gives your end users some flexibility.  They can define their own page and select your template - so "About" could be used for "About," "About Me," "Our Story," etc.  No need to know *which* page will be used for the about page in advance.

Just define two extra php files in your theme:

- `about-template.php`
- `contact-template.php`

Then make sure the files include a header that looks something like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: About Page
*/
?>
... The rest of your regular template file continues below ...
```

---

### Using Page Templates

One these custom page templates are defined by your theme, there's nothing special you need to do to use them.  Just create pages like you normally would within WordPress, but make sure you select the template you want to use from the Page Attributes meta box:

[image: WordPress Page Attributes]

This example is from my theme, which defines additional "Archive," "Blog," and "Landing" templates.  The Default Template is just what it sounds like, the default `page.php` template.

Comment: thanx, and how do I activate them from inside wp-admin?

Comment: See my edit for details.